# Calling GraphicsMagick command using T_SQL xp_cmdshell procedure

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, graphicsmagick, xp-cmdshell

I have been trying to call a GraphicsMagick command through the T-SQL xp_cmdshell procedure, but I am getting errors with the same.

The command I am trying to call is as below :
gm convert "\dklyefxdb1\X\Backup\apple_raw.jpg" -scale 200x250 "\dklyefxdb1\X\Backup\apple_raw_resize.jpg"

The SQL code which I am executing is as follows :

```
Exec sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
Reconfigure
GO

exec xp_cmdshell 'gm convert "\\dklyefxdb1\X\Backup\apple_raw.jpg" -scale 200x250 "\\dklyefxdb1\X\Backup\apple_raw_resize.jpg"'
GO
```

I am getting the following error after executing this code:

> 'gm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Please note that GraphicsMagick is installed on the Server where SQL Server sits.

Other point to note here is that if I run the same command through cmd on the server, it runs successfully.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add full path to gm:

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'C:\..\gm convert "\\dklyefxdb1\X\Backup\apple_raw.jpg" -scale 200x250 "\\dklyefxdb1\X\Backup\apple_raw_resize.jpg"'
```

or `SET PATH` environment variable

Comment: Now its giving me error as below :
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @AnkurBatra Do you add full path to gm.exe??? I don't know where in your filesystem it is, it was just example.

Comment: I entered the full path :
C:\Program Files (x86)\GraphicsMagick-1.3.21-Q8\gm

Comment: @AnkurBatra Add additional '' or `\\\`

Comment: Paste in your question exec with full path

Comment: Where should I put  '' or `\\

Comment: exec xp_cmdshell 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GraphicsMagick-1.3.21-Q8\gm.exe convert "\\dklyefxdb1\X\Backup\apple_raw.jpg" -scale 200x250 "\\dklyefxdb1\X\Backup\apple_raw_resize.jpg"'

Comment: `exec xp_cmdshell 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GraphicsMagick-1.3.21-Q8\\gm.exe convert "\\dklyefxdb1\X\Backup\apple_raw.jpg" -scale 200x250 "\\dklyefxdb1\X\Backup\apple_raw_resize.jpg"'`

Comment: @AnkurBatra The problem may be in path because it contains space, try moving gm.exe to `D:\GM\gm.exe`

Comment: still the same error as C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: @AnkurBatra Try with moving to location without spaces in name or execute in cmd `SET` and see if it is in PATH variable reference to gm folder